# How to prevent tab navigation to a control, while allowing directional navigation to that control

Tags: wpf, focus, tabbing, keyboard-navigation

In WPF (MVVM, no code-behind), say I have the following xaml:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button>Normal 1</Button>
    <Button>Special</Button> <!--This button should not tab focus, but still focus via arrow keys-->
    <Button>Normal 2</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

By default, you can (1) tab between the buttons or (2) up/down arrow between the buttons. I want to make one of the buttons -- the *Special* button -- **not** focusable via tab, yet still focusable via up/down. I tried `IsTabStop="False"`, but that also prevents focusing that button via directional navigation (up/down arrows).

How can I **remove a single button from tab navigation**, while **continuing to allow directional navigation**? Tabbing and arrowing should be **unaffected for all other controls**.

I've tried combinations of `IsTabStop`, `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation`, and `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation` to no avail. Maybe I haven't found the right mix. Or maybe there is another approach. Ideas?

---

**EDIT**: Okay, I am adding a bounty. To be clear, I am looking for a MVVM, no code-behind way to decorate a control (e.g. via style, attached property, attached behavior, etc), such that it is removed from the tab order, while remaining a valid directional navigation target. Hard coding knowledge of the controls into the Window (or similar), is not acceptable. This needs to be a general, reusable solution. Something like: `<Button AllowDirectionalNavigationButPreventTabNavigation="True"/>`.

Comment: That should help :
[WPF: How to disable tab navigation without also disabling arrow key navigation?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210659/wpf-how-to-disable-tab-navigation-without-also-disabling-arrow-key-navigation

Comment: @Joseph I found that question, but that person had a different scenario (they were using a listview), and neither of the suggested solutions solve my exact issue. Plus, the accepted solution uses code-behind and requires the window to know about the tab behavior of all of controls within it -- I want the control to dictate it's own behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about that option. You stick your special button into another container and put KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None" on that container. I've just tried it and it looks like I can achieve what you need.

```
<StackPanel >
  <Button>Normal 1</Button>
  <StackPanel KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None">
    <Button>Special</Button><!--This button should not tab focus, but still focus via arrow keys-->
  </StackPanel>
  <Button>Normal 2</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: This is the correct solution; the `TabNavigation` property controls the logical navigation behavior of an element's *children*, so in the OP's case, the "special" button should be wrapped in another container.

Comment: Perfect! My real scenario was more complicated, but this was the idea/info I needed to get it there. In my custom control's style, I set `Focusable=False` and `KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation=None`. Then, in the custom control's control template, I set `Focusable=True` and it achieves exactly what I wanted.

Comment: If you do this on a button contained into a Grid, it works at first glance. But if you click on the button, the focus still come back on the button (I'm using MaterialDesignToolkit). Any idea to conclude this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

here how i did it :

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmLight1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ignore="http://www.ignore.com"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="KeyDown">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay,Path=KeyDownCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <StackPanel>
        <Button>Normal 1</Button>
        <Button>Special</Button>
        <!--Should not tab focus, yet still focus via arrow keys-->
        <Button>Normal 2</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

i am using the mvvmlight, and the EventToCommand is used to intercept the KeyDown Event and direct it to the following command in the ViewModel:

```
 private RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> _keyDownCommand;
    public RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs> KeyDownCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _keyDownCommand
                ?? (_keyDownCommand = new RelayCommand<KeyEventArgs>(
                (s) =>
                {
                    if (s.Key == Key.Tab)
                    {
                        s.Handled = true;
                    }
                }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this disables tab for the entire window. I'm looking for a way to disable tab for only one control.

Comment: What control! do you mean the StackPanel ?

Comment: For just the one button. The special button. All other buttons should still be tabbable. The question is: how to remove a control (e.g. button) from the tab order, while leaving it as a valid directional navigation target.